Fixed length table with columns taking up max-width
I'm unable to figure out the CSS styles I need to apply to achieve the following:

I would like an HTML table with a max-width of up to 400px.
Within the table, each column should have a max width of 300 px.
The content within each column should always take up as much space as possible (up to 300px).
If the columns overflow the width of the table, then the table should be horizontally scrollable.

I created a codepen for this: https://codepen.io/steviedean2004/pen/LYoWREV
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
So far, I have tried this (the !important is just to be for sure).
table {
  table-layout: fixed !important;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

th {
  max-width: 300px !important;
}

td {
  max-width: 300px !important;
}

However, it seems I'm unable to get the content to take up the width of the column (it always just shrinks, see image).

you are missing the <tbody> tag...

Good point--I added that in, but still getting the same issue. DYT I need to add some styles to tbody as well?

to have a horizontal scroll you must place the entire table in a container with width: 400px and horizontal-scroll: auto. Otherwise in the future, use a Stackoverflow snippet, and not on codepen.

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

You will need to insert a div inside the td with the content inside of the div. See this SO link

That's absolutely valid Jojo. Yes I should've minimized my code a bit before posting this.

Genius, Mehdi! That seems to work!

Mehdi was correct. Putting a div inside the  and then putting the styles on the div worked.
e.g.


.my-table-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.my-table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th>div, td>div {
  width:max-content;
  max-width:300px;
}

.result-header {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.result-header-title {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.h-300 {
  height: 300px;
}

/* Table styling */
.my-table,
.my-table th,
.my-table td {
  background-color: white;
}
.my-table thead tr {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
.my-table--sticky-header thead {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
<div class="my-table-wrapper h-300">
  <table class="my-table my-table--sticky-header">
    <thead>
      <th>Field here</th>
      <th>Field here</th>
      <th><div>Maybe a super long field here</div></th>
      <th>Field here</th>
      <th>Field here</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some more data, but really long data goes here and maybe it overflows too</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some more data, but really long data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some more data, but really long data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some more data, but really long data goes here</div></td>
        <td><div>Some data goes here</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



